# snap permissions for home directory for Octave

Tags: permissions, snap, octave

I installed the `octave` snap yesterday, but when I run `octave`, it does not have permissions to access my `$HOME`. How do I enable permissions?

```
ctaggart@rustasia:~/octave-add$ octave
octave: X11 DISPLAY environment variable not set
octave: disabling GUI features
GNU Octave, version 5.1.0
Copyright (C) 2019 John W. Eaton and others.
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions.
There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  For details, type 'warranty'.

Octave was configured for "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".

Additional information about Octave is available at https://www.octave.org.

Please contribute if you find this software useful.
For more information, visit https://www.octave.org/get-involved.html

Read https://www.octave.org/bugs.html to learn how to submit bug reports.
For information about changes from previous versions, type 'news'.

warning: load_path: .: Permission denied
octave:1> ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

After reading https://docs.snapcraft.io/interface-management, I thought this was going to work:

```
sudo snap connect octave:home :home
error: cannot resolve connection, slot snap name is empty
```

Details of the snap:

```
ctaggart@rustasia:~/octave-add$ snap info octave
name:      octave
summary:   Interactive programming environment for numerical computations
publisher: GNU Octave (octave-snap✓)
contact:   snap@octave.org
license:   unset
description: |
  GNU Octave is a high-level interpreted language, primarily intended for
  numerical computations. It provides capabilities for the numerical
  solution of linear and nonlinear problems, and for performing other
  numerical experiments. It also provides extensive graphics capabilities
  for data visualization and manipulation. Octave is normally used through
  its interactive command line interface, but it can also be used to write
  non-interactive programs. The Octave language is quite similar to
  Matlab so that most programs are easily portable.
commands:
  - octave
  - octave.octave-cli
snap-id:      AC5zoejRZUR3QS4V1ZCktZ2yUUz3ubRb
tracking:     beta
refresh-date: yesterday at 05:54 UTC
channels:
  stable:    –                          
  candidate: –                          
  beta:      5.1.0 2019-06-13 (5) 192MB -
  edge:      5.1.0 2019-06-13 (5) 192MB -
installed:   5.1.0            (5) 192MB -
```

And connections:

```
ctaggart@rustasia:~/octave-add$ snap connections octave
Interface       Plug                   Slot  Notes
desktop         octave:desktop         -     -
desktop-legacy  octave:desktop-legacy  -     -
home            octave:home            -     -
opengl          octave:opengl          -     -
pulseaudio      octave:pulseaudio      -     -
unity7          octave:unity7          -     -
wayland         octave:wayland         -     -
x11             octave:x11             -     -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have octave installed in my machine, so I'm showing the process using the Brave browser.

1. Start software-center, click on the **Installed** tab, find octave from the list and click.
   [image: step 1]
2. Now, select the **Permissions** button, from here you can set necessary access permission to your app.
   [image: step 2]

Comment: That is very helpful. Those permissions should match up to the `snap connections octave`. I'd like to know how to set the permission for "Access files in your home folder" from the command line, since I I'm ssh'ing to a VM that does not have a GUI.

Comment: @CameronTaggart easy `snap connect octave:home`
. You can press tab to guide you after every word :D

Comment: After installing brave with `sudo snap install brave`, all octave's connections were connected. The `snap connect` and `snap disconnect` commands work as intended. There is a set up bug in there somewhere, but probably going to mark this as resolved.

Comment: @CameronTaggart why did you install brave.... ?  i took the screenshots for brave because i didn't have octave installed in my machine ....

Comment: I installed brave to troubleshoot connections and find out if it was a bug in octave. After installing it, connections started working. I noticed that `core` `16-2.39.3` was installed as a dependency. Connections are still working for octave with brave removed. I curious what the root cause was, but am going to move on. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @CameronTaggart ah, i see. i was kind of confused. have a good day.