# Applications Can't Read My Other Hard Drives?

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, kubuntu, 19.04

I have 3 hard drives and I've noticed that my applications can't read from the HDD's that the system isn't installed on.

I can't read anything from it and keep getting permission denied errors, even if I try and use a link from the desktop.

Is there no way to get around this aside for running as sudo? It seems kind of crazy to use sudo for something like Discord just so I can post pictures.

I could also just copy the files to my system disk, but this doesn't seem like the best solution.

What should I do about this? Is there any way to allow programs to be able to read from other hard drives?

Note: The particular folder I'm interested in has the proper file permissions which were changed using `chown`. All of the folders above it were as well.

Comment: Are the applications in question installed as snaps? Check with `snap list`. If so, take a look at the example in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158550/snap-permissions-for-home-directory-for-octave .

Comment: @mook765 I believe they are actually. Yes, they are. I didn't notice this.

Answer (score 0):

I searched almost everywhere for the solution. But it is actually simple. Go to

> settings -> Applications

and select the application you want to access your files in other drives.  And turn on the option **read/write on removable devices**.